# Extract value from a string in C# from a specific position

Tags: c#, string

I have *bunch of files* in a folder and I am looping through them.
How do I *extract the value* from the below example? I need the value **0519** only.

```
DOC 75-20-0519-1.PDF
```

The below code gives the *complete part include -1*.

```
Convert.ToInt32(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(objFile).Split('-')[2]);
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Your code looks fine and should work fine. Double check you `objFile`.

Comment: Works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cJizlM

Comment: What do you mean by "The below code gives the complete part include -1"? I don't see why the code you've provided would not be returning just "0519", unless `objFile` wasn't what you think it is, or if the hyphens in the file name weren't actual hyphens (char 45) - but they are in what you've posted.

Comment: Wait a second ... do you mean you are losing the leading 0? That would be expected when converting to int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REGEX for this

```
Match match  = Regex.Match("DOC 75-20-0519-1.PDF", @"DOC\s+\d+\-\d+\-(\d+)\-\d+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string data = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try *regular expressions* in order to *match* the value.

**pattern:**

```
 [0-9]+            - one ore more digits
 (?=[^0-9][0-9]+$) - followed by not a digit and one or more digits and end of string
```

**code:**

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string file = "DOC 75-20-0519-1.PDF";

  // "0519"
  string result = Regex
    .Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file), @"[0-9]+(?=[^0-9][0-9]+$)")
    .Value;
```

If `Split('-')` *fails*, and you have an *entire string* as a result, it seems that you have a *wrong delimiter*. It can be, say, one of the *dashes*:

```
  "DOC 75–20–0519–1.PDF";  // n-dash
  "DOC 75—20—0519—1.PDF";  // m-dash
```

Comment: While this works, I wonder why OP's code apparently does not (for him). I couldn't reproduce his problem. So I wonder if this will give him the same problem?

Comment: @Fildor: thank you! It's quite possible if cureent code "gives the complete part include -1" it seems that delimiter is wrong